# After apt-get update and upgrade, do I need to recompile and re-install software that I did not install via apt-get install?

Tags: apt, make, openssl, squid, configure

In particular, I noticed that my OpenSSL has been upgraded after a system update via **`sudo apt-get update`** and **`sudo apt-get upgrade`**.

As I installed my Squid server by manually compiling, configuring and installing via **`./configure`**, **`make all`** and **`make install`**, I am concerned whether my current Squid is still using the old OpenSSL software.

Do I need to recompile and re-install Squid in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your OpenSSL library is dynamically linked to the Squid executable then it will use the current OpenSSL library.  It has no choice as the older one will have been removed during the system upgrade.

On the other hand, if Squid was statically linked at compile time to the OpenSSL library, it will be using the old one.

Run:-

```
ldd <path to squid executable>
```

and see if the OpenSSL library is listed.  If it is, then it's dynamically linked and you're OK.

Comment: There's no explicit openssl present in the output. There is a libssl.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f80ccb71000) though. I guess I should be OK. Thanks!